# Дробление EXCEL файла на несколько по строкам (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Имеется Файл, порядка 930000 строк, требуется его разделить на ~93 файла EXEL по 10000 строк в каждом. Ниже скрипт, но он не отрабатывает.

```
Sub Test()
Dim currentRows As Long, sourceCol As Long, LastRow as Long
Dim currentRowValue As String, sourcews As String, rows2 As Long
Dim sheetName As String, Исходная As Excel.Workbook, Конечная As Excel.Workbook
Set Исходная = ActiveWorkbook
sourcews = ActiveSheet.Name
sourceCol = 1
RowCoun = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row
file2 = 1
 МакросКнига ("C:\1\Moscow_Samara" & file2 & ".xls")
Set Конечная = Workbooks.Open("C:\1\Moscow_Samara" & file2 & ".xls")
For currentRow = 1 To RowCount
rows2 = rows2 + 1
currentRowValue = Исходная.Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
If Not (IsEmpty(currentRowValue) or currentValue = "") Then
Конечная.Worksheets(sheetName).Select
 LastRow = Cells(Конечная.Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row
If LastRow = 1 And rows2 = 1 Then LastRow = 0
 Range(Конечная.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1), Конечная.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1)) _ 
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Исходная.WorkSheets(sourcews).Activate
End If
If rows2 = 10000 Then
Конечная.Close SaveChanges:=True
    file2 = file2 + 1
rows2 = 0
sheetName = "Финиш" & file2
 МакросКнига ("C:\1\Moscow_Samara" & file2 & ".xls")
Set Конечная = Workbooks.Open("C:\1\Moscow_Samara" & file2 & ".xls")
End If
Next
End Sub
  Sub МакросКнига (FName As String)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName: = FName, FileFormat:= _ 
xlNormal, Password:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:= False _ 
, CreateBackup:=False
EndSub
```

Comment: Есть уже готовый код, но он не отрабатывает. Пытаюсь его запихнуть.

Comment: Мы в вас верим. :) Справка по редактированию [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Фууууух, переписал

Comment: Легче новый написать )  Строки переносить все? Весь пользовательский диапазон? Шапка таблицы есть? Копировать ее во все файлы? Имена создаваемых файлов какие?

Comment: Вот то то и оно, что вариантов как написать больше нет. Строки требуется перенести все, Копирование должно производиться следующим алгоритмом: 10000 скопировал в отдельный файл, создает файл где следующие 10000 строк (И так до конца файла Должно получиться 93-94 файла) порядка 20 столбцов. Уповаю на вас, всезнающий божественный StackOwerflow, и молюсь будучи эникейщиком....

Comment: Шапку копировать желательно но не обязательно, Имена можно любые, даже простое именование от 1 до 93

Comment: *Копирование должно производиться следующим алгоритмом* Хреновенький алгоритм. Разумнее копировать лист в новую книгу, а потом давить там всё лишнее. Не будет проблем с шапками и форматированием.

Comment: @Akina, согласен что алгоритм полное ...мо, но задача звучит именно так...

Comment: Стоп! Я сейчас пишу именно так: копирование листа, удаление всего лишнего. На листе остается только нужный диапазон. У Вас задача другая?

Comment: @vikttur, задача стоит такая, Есть файл 930000 записей (Строк) и нужно этот файл разделить на отдельные книги по 10000 записей(Строк). Все эти 930000 находятся на одном листе. Соответственно первая книга содержит с 1 по 100000 записи, вторая с 10001 по 20000 и так далее, можно в приципе распилить все это на листы и потом ctl-c ctrl-v в разные книги, но я думаю это будет дольше чем будет обрабатывать скрипт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рядом с файлом-источником создается папка (если такой нет), в которую складываются новые книги.

```
Sub SeparateRows()
Dim wBook As Object
Dim sFldr As String, sFName As String
Dim lRw As Long, lStep As Long
Dim i As Long, k As Long, n As Long
    ' принимаем, что данные начинаются с первой строки'
    lRw = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count ' количество строк'
    If lRw < lStep Then Exit Sub ' разбивать нечего'
    lStep = 10000 ' к-во строк в блоке'

    sFldr = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Разбивка" & "\" ' путь к папке для сохранения'
    If Dir(sFldr, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir sFldr ' создаем, если нет'
' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With

    For i = 1 To lRw Step lStep ' циклом поблочно'
        With Workbooks.Add ' новая книга'
            ws1.Copy Before:=.Sheets(1) ' копируем лист в новую книгу'

            With .Sheets(1)
                .Name = i ' имя листа'

                If i > 1 Then ' удаляем лишние строки'
                    .Rows(i + lStep & ":" & lRw + 1).Delete
                    .Rows(1 & ":" & i - 1).Delete
                Else
                    .Rows(lStep + 1 & ":" & lRw + 1).Delete
                End If
            End With

            For k = .Sheets.Count To 2 Step -1: .Sheets(k).Delete: Next k ' удаляем листы'

            If i + lStep - 1 < lRw Then
                sFName = "Строки_" & i & "_" & i + lStep - 1 & ".xlsx" ' имя книги'
            Else
                sFName = "Строки_" & i & "_" & lRw & ".xlsx"
            End If

            .SaveAs Filename:=sFldr & sFName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            .Close: n = n + 1 ' счетчик созданных книг'
        End With
    Next i

    Set wBook = Nothing
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
    MsgBox "Обработка завершена" & Chr$(10) & "Создано файлов: " & n, 64, ""
End Sub
```

В коде указано внутреннее имя листа - *ws1*. Его можно изменить в редакторе *VBA*. Но можно в коде заменить на *Worksheets("имя_листа")*

*lStep* - задаем количество строк в одном блоке

Comment: У меня тут одна идея родилась, подскажите как реализовать.            'Rows (2+(i-1)*10000:i*10000).Select' ругается на :. Получается неправильно. Как реализовать формулу в Rows?

Comment: *Rows(i & ":" & k)* Посмотрите в коде, там есть похожая строка. Зачем выделять строки? Работа кода с объектами листа медленная Любое лишнее движение на листе - лишние тормоза.

Comment: Я придумал простое решение, сейчас рихтую.

Comment: Мой код не подошел?

Comment: Решение хорошее, но есть вариант который легче,  и удобнее. Насчет быстрее не знаю, пока не запускается